# No of reflexive relations of a set

Tags: combinatorics, relations

[Number of reflexive relations defined on a set A with n elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88032/number-of-reflexive-relations-defined-on-a-set-a-with-n-elements)

I understand that for n elements of a set we have 2^(n^2-n) ways of checking whether a function is reflexive or not.
But shouldn't the n confirmed reflexive relations be added to give a total of 2^(n^2-n)+n relations

Why is it that we dont include the n confirmed reflexive cases while counting

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to spell that out a bit more. Where in the linked question or the answer to it do you see "$n$ confirmed reflexive cases"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up a relation, which is a subset $R\subseteq A\times A$, with their elements $(x,y)\in R$. A reflexive relation $R$ has as elements at least all pairs $(x,x)$ for $x\in A$. If $|A|=n$ this means that the $n$ elements $(x,x)$ will be in any reflexive relation. This leaves you with $n^2-n$ other possible elements of $A\times A$ that might or might not be elements of $R$. Hence the number of possible reflexive relations $R$ is $2^{n^2-n}$.

For example when $A=\{1,2,3\}$, every reflexive relation contains the elements $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$, so
$$
R = \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), \dots \}.
$$
Now for the remaining $3^2-3 = 6$ elements
$$
(1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,3), (3,1), (3,2)
$$
they can either be in $R$ or not be in $R$, leaving us with $6$ yes/no choices. There are $2^6$ ways to make these $6$ choices.

Comment: Oh I see. So while counting the other possibilities we don't include the n number of (x,x) 's as individual subsets of R. Is this what you mean?

Comment: The sets $\{(x,x)\}$ are not reflexive relations (when $n>1$). I added an example for $A=\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: Ohh I finally understood. The example cleared my doubts. Thank you!