# How to find the number of binary relations?

Tags: binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of relations that are both symmetric and reflexive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12139/number-of-relations-that-are-both-symmetric-and-reflexive)

Let $X$ be a set with $8$ elements.

How many binary relations on $X$ are either reflexive or symmetric or both?

show work. you need not simplify the answer.

Comment: Funny -- "show work" also appears in [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1804/6622), but there the request goes in the other direction...

Comment: Here is a start. For symmetric, there are $56$ ordered pairs of *distinct* elements. For any such pair, you can say yes or no. So there are $2^{56}$ symmetric relations. A similar argument (but be careful about equality) will count the symmetric relations. Add. The reflexive **and** symmetric have been double-counted.

Comment: It is the number which are reflexive *plus* the number which are symmetric *minus* the number which are both (to avoid double counting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a set with 8 elements, a binary relation, $R$ can be thought of as a set of pairs of elements of the set for which that relation is true.  That is, $(a,b) \in R \leftrightarrow aRb$ is true.  As such, if there are 8 elements, then there 64 possible pairs (order matters).  If the relation is reflexive, then this implies that $(a,a) \in R$ for all $a$.  So we know that 8 of the pairs must be in the relation.  This leaves 56 pairs which can either be in or not be in.  So there are $2^{56}$ possible reflexive relations.

Similar combinatorics can be applied to find the answer for symmetric and both.

Comment: You are saying symmetric when you mean reflexive.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you are completely correct.  How dumb of me.  Fixed in most recent edit.