# Number of different relations that are both symmetric and reflexive on a set with 4 elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, relations

Let S = {x | x is a prime number and 1 < x < 10}. Let N be the number of different relations that are both reflexive and symmetric that can be defined on S. Since there is only 4 elements in S={2,3,5,7}, SxS has $2^n$ elements, so only 16 elements. However, I find that the solution is N=64. I am confused how it can be such a high number. The only reflexive pairs that I can find are (2,2),(3,3),(5,5),(7,7), and any other symmetric pair would not be reflexive anyway. Any insight on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of relations that are both symmetric and reflexive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12139/number-of-relations-that-are-both-symmetric-and-reflexive): on a set of $n$ elements, it is $2^{\frac{n^2-n}{2}}.$

Answer (score 2):

As you mention, $S \times S$ has $16$ elements; this is because $S$ has $4$ elements and $4^2 = 16$. The number of *subsets* of $S \times S$ is then $2^{16}$, which is what allows $N$ to be so large.

To see why $N = 64$, we first note that, as you mention, $(2,2), (3,3), (5,5), (7,7)$ must all be elements of any reflexive and symmetric relation.

Additionally, $(i,j)$ is in our relation if and only if $(j,i)$ is (this is what it means to be symmetric). As such, our relations are characterized by whether or not they include the pairs $(2,3), (2,5), (2,7), (3,5), (3,7), (5,7)$. For each of those $6$ pairs, we have $2$ choices (to include the pair or exclude the pair). This gives us $N = 2^6 = 64$ reflexive and symmetric relations.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Fixed.